# Bluetooth Synchronization

Tags: java, android, synchronization, bluetooth

I create an instance of a class that connects to a Bluetooth Socket. Then from the calling class I write bytes to that Socket by calling another method of the newly created instance. Unfortuanetly I get a write exception, because the write occurs before the initial connection is created.

I know I need to synchronize the calls somehow, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just implemented a queue, seems to be the most effective way.